# Fresh .Net 6.0 WPF application not working with Visual 2022

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I am trying make some WPF .Net 6.0 application (I am currently working with .Net core 3.1)

If I create an application from scratch I can select .Net 6.0

[image]

When I try to compile I get the following error

> The TargetFramework value 'net6.0-windows' was not recognized. It may
> be misspelled. If not, then the TargetFrameworkIdentifier and/or
> TargetFrameworkVersion properties must be specified explicitly.

In my csproj I can see the net6.0-windows as it should be

[image]

But if I go to the properties I can't see any frameworks in the corresponding drop down list

[image]

I have modified / repaired / uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio 2022 17.4.4 (and also rebooted countless times)

I have double checked the options of my installation and they look ok

[image]

[image]

and If I go the command line to check the installed SDKs it also look ok

[image]

I have also tried with or without global.json file

What more can I try

Comment: The install did not go well.  You'll have to spin the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune, after checking machine health.

Comment: What happens if you run `dotnet build` at command prompt? At least, that should tell if you meet a .NET SDK issue or a VS one.

Comment: @LexLi I get the following error  `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.416\NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Invalid restore input. Invalid target framework 'unsupported'.` So it looks like it doesn't look in the correct SDK folder. I also tried the -f option to try to force net6.0 but the result is the same

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool?tabs=windows Clean up the machine by removing all .NET Core SDKs. Then install .NET 6/7 to resolve this issue. And then install 3.1 back if you still need it.

Comment: I kept on playing around with paths and the global.json to finally found one of this file "lost" in one folder above my solution, that finally prevented the link to the one I put in c:\Users\MyAccount\global.json . I deleted this file and suddenly everything is working fine. Thanks for your time and inputs.